# How to print correct multiplication of big number in PHP

Tags: php

I was trying to print multiplication of big numbers and they are resulting in float type scientific number.

```
var_dump((double)('290287121823'*'290287121823'));
```

I tried the function number_format and preg_replace to remove all ','. But after number_format the result is not correct.

Used following code:

```
preg_replace("/,/", "", (number_format(('290287121823'*'290287121823'))));
```

> Output received: 84266613096281242861568
>
> Expected correct output: 84266613096281243382112

Comment: if you need integers with more than 64 bits, you should have a look at the [GMP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.gmp.php)

Comment: Can we do it without using GMP or BC Maths?

Comment: How do you compute your result? The result of this multiplication is `84266613096281242843329`, right ? The two last digits are 3, so the last digit of the final result is 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The large numbers are computed digits by digits. Like we learn at school (see [Long multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Long_multiplication)).

ex:

```
//    17
//  x 27
//  ----
//   119
// + 34 
// -----
// = 459
```

Here is a function (which should be optimized) but shows you the principle.

```
echo bn_mul('17', '27'), PHP_EOL; // 459
echo bn_mul('157', '27'), PHP_EOL; // 4239
echo bn_mul('1234', '6627'), PHP_EOL; // 8177718
echo bn_mul('23958233', '5830'), PHP_EOL; // 139676498390
echo bn_mul('290287121823', '290287121823'), PHP_EOL; // 84266613096281242843329
```

Implementation:

```
function bn_mul($n2, $n1) {

    $l1 = strlen($n1);
    $l2 = strlen($n2);

    $rows = [];

    for ($idx1 = $l1 - 1 ; $idx1 >= 0 ; $idx1--) {
        // get digit
        $d1 = substr($n1, $idx1, 1) ;

        $carry = 0; // reset carry
        $row = []; // store digit of $d1 x each digits of $n2

        // prepend 0 (10 * num rows)
        for ($x=0 ; $x<count($rows) ; $x++) $row[] = 0;

        for ($idx2 = $l2 - 1 ; $idx2 >= 0 ; $idx2--) {

            // get digit
            $d2 = substr($n2, $idx2, 1) ;
            // multiplication of digit 1 x digit 2 + current carry
            $r = $d1 * $d2 + $carry;

            $carry = 0;

            // compute carry
            if ($r >= 10) {
                $carry = substr($r, 0, -1);
                $r = substr($r, -1);
            }
            $row[] = $r ;
        }

        if ($carry) $row[] = $carry;

        $rows[] = $row ;
    }


    // Sum digits of rows
    $total = [] ;
    $carry = 0 ;
    for ($x=0;$x < count(end($rows)) ; $x++){
        $tot = $carry;
        $carry = 0;
        foreach ($rows as $row){
            if (isset($row[$x])) $tot += $row[$x] ;
        }
        while ($tot >= 10) {
            $tot -= 10;
            $carry++;
        }
        $total[$x] = $tot;
    }

    return strrev(implode($total));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind that even if PHP is NOT typesafe, there are types in the background.

When you look up the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.float.php) you'll find out, that floating points only have a precision up to 14 digits. Therefore, all trailing numbers are "cut off". The magnitude remains and it will print in scientific format but you can't really know what's "below" that 14 digits. Therefore, your try to convert the result is doomed to fail in the first place.

Example:

```
12345678910111213
              ^^^ get's cut off
```